# Insertar Variable PHP dentro de correo con cuerpo HTML

Tags: php, html

Amigos tengo el siguiente código:

```
$borrame2 = "ALGUIEN";
$borrame3 = "https://eldomain/fnlStep.php?nbrUsr=$var5Esp";
$borrame4 = "<a class='mcnButton ' title='Ver Voucher' href=".$borrame3." target='_blank' style='font-weight: bold;letter-spacing: normal;line-height: 100%;text-align: center;text-decoration: none;color: #FFFFFF;'>Ver Voucher</a>";


<!doctype html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xmlns:v="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:vml" xmlns:o="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office">
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<title></title>
</head>
<body>
<span class="mcnPreviewText" style="display:none; font-size:0px; line-height:0px; max-height:0px; max-width:0px; opacity:0; overflow:hidden; visibility:hidden; mso-hide:all;"></span>
<center>
  <table align="center" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" height="100%" width="100%" id="bodyTable">
    <tr>
      <td align="center" valign="top" id="bodyCell"><table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%" class="templateContainer">
          <tr>
            <td valign="top" id="templatePreheader"></td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td valign="top" id="templateHeader"><table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%" class="mcnImageBlock" style="min-width:100%;">
                <tbody class="mcnImageBlockOuter">
                  <tr>
                    <td valign="top" style="padding:9px" class="mcnImageBlockInner"><table align="left" width="100%" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" class="mcnImageContentContainer" style="min-width:100%;">
                        <tbody>
                          <tr>
                            <td class="mcnImageContent" valign="top" style="padding-right: 9px; padding-left: 9px; padding-top: 0; padding-bottom: 0; text-align:center;"><img align="center" alt="" src="https://mcusercontent.com/538e9f373ab4cbd46a555c96e/images/1c708191-16ea-ec15-8509-f2ab46a6bfaf.png" width="564" style="max-width:4808px; padding-bottom: 0; display: inline !important; vertical-align: bottom;" class="mcnImage"></td>
                          </tr>
                        </tbody>
                      </table></td>
                  </tr>
                </tbody>
              </table></td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td valign="top" id="templateBody"><table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%" class="mcnTextBlock" style="min-width:100%;">
                <tbody class="mcnTextBlockOuter">
                  <tr>
                    <td valign="top" class="mcnTextBlockInner" style="padding-top:9px;"><table align="left" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" style="max-width:100%; min-width:100%;" width="100%" class="mcnTextContentContainer">
                        <tbody>
                          <tr>
                            <td valign="top" class="mcnTextContent" style="padding-top:0; padding-right:18px; padding-bottom:9px; padding-left:18px;"><h1 style="text-align: left;"><br>
                                <font face="Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif">'.$borrame2.',&nbsp;</font>el pago de tu pedido se ha procesado correctamente</h1>
                              <br>
                              <br>
                              &nbsp;</td>
                          </tr>
                        </tbody>
                      </table></td>
                  </tr>
                </tbody>
              </table>
              <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%" class="mcnButtonBlock" style="min-width:100%;">
                <tbody class="mcnButtonBlockOuter">
                  <tr>
                    <td style="padding-top:0; padding-right:18px; padding-bottom:18px; padding-left:18px;" valign="top" align="center" class="mcnButtonBlockInner"><table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" class="mcnButtonContentContainer" style="border-collapse: separate !important;border-radius: 4px;background-color: #000000;">
                        <tbody>
                          <tr>
                            <td align="center" valign="middle" class="mcnButtonContent" style="font-family: Arial; font-size: 16px; padding: 18px;">'.$borrame2.'</td>
                          </tr>
                        </tbody>
                      </table></td>
                  </tr>
                </tbody>
              </table></td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td valign="top" id="templateFooter"><table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%" class="mcnDividerBlock" style="min-width:100%;">
                <tbody class="mcnDividerBlockOuter">
                  <tr>
                    <td class="mcnDividerBlockInner" style="min-width: 100%; padding: 10px 18px 25px;"><table class="mcnDividerContent" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%" style="min-width: 100%;border-top: 2px solid #EEEEEE;">
                        <tbody>
                          <tr>
                            <td><span></span></td>
                          </tr>
                        </tbody>
                      </table></td>
                  </tr>
                </tbody>
              </table>
              <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%" class="mcnTextBlock" style="min-width:100%;">
                <tbody class="mcnTextBlockOuter">
                  <tr>
                    <td valign="top" class="mcnTextBlockInner" style="padding-top:9px;"><table align="left" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" style="max-width:100%; min-width:100%;" width="100%" class="mcnTextContentContainer">
                        <tbody>
                          <tr>
                            <td valign="top" class="mcnTextContent" style="padding-top:0; padding-right:18px; padding-bottom:9px; padding-left:18px;"> Este es un correo automático.&nbsp;Por&nbsp;favor no lo respondas.</td>
                          </tr>
                        </tbody>
                      </table></td>
                  </tr>
                </tbody>
              </table></td>
          </tr>
        </table></td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</center>
</body>
</html>
```

Como pueden ver el código anterior corresponde a el body de un correo que se envía usando php, el problema es de que estoy intentando insertar el contenido de la variable `$borrame4` justo en medio del código HTML del correo, pero me marca error, todo esto tiene que ir adentro de una variable en PHP lo he sacado para que podamos visualizarlo de una manera adecuada y con el código completamente ordenado, es cuando intento insertar el contenido de la variable $borrame2 cuando se da el problema, no entiendo si es la manera en la que estoy concatenado los datos la que me esta dando problemas.

Comment: Primero que nada... ordena tu html, a pesar de estar dentro de una variable, puedes acomodarlo de modo que sea más legible. Y el error que te manda, es por que has olvidado concatenar el borrame2 ... https://i.gyazo.com/482a45974f264d8b2ab294c3c34e2362.png

Comment: Agradezco tu comentario @Excorpion, pero la variable $borrame2 la tengo definida un poco mas arriba.

Comment: listo, código editado @Excorpion

Comment: Ahora, repíteme el error por que ahora mismo no me aparece XD

Comment: snipper.io/s/-Ma5f4K2GnWjWOhB1Fl1 ahi tengo el codigo amigo @Excorpion